# cassandra hints are high due to gc pause events - this is creating a cycle

Tags: cassandra

Our clusters were running great from days and all sudden today morning hints are high. And they will not go down naturally.

What we are seeing is, gc is taking longer time than 200ms which is causing nodes to be DOWN and thereby leading to increase in hints. This is a vicious circle, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Machine config: 128GB RAM, 2TB hard disk, 24 core machine. JVM heap size 16Gb, GCpausemillisecods 200ms, parallelgcthreads 8.

Please let me know, how can I tune GC config to break this gc pause to hint loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We increased the size of JVM heap to 32GB, and took memtable off heap for write heavy customers.